# Event click doesn't work on Ng2Table

Tags: angular

I created this column showing a delete icon and when I click call a deletePlan function but it does not work

list-plans.ts

```
item['deleteOpt'] = "<i data-id="+item.id+" (click)='deletePlan(data)' class='material-icons' style='color: red; font-size: 20px; cursor: pointer'>delete</i>";
```

table in list-plans.html

```
<ng-table [config]="config" (tableChanged)="onChangeTable(config)" (cellClicked)="onCellClick($event)" [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns"></ng-table>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what 'it does not work' actually mean here

Comment: when I click on the icon it simply does not call the function as if it did not exist

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: I just see the function (cellClicked) = "onCellClick ($event)" being called when I click anywhere in the table